# Error when try to parse String to Double

Tags: java, android, android-maps

i have a string like this

```
106.826820,-6.303850,0
```

which i get from parsing the google Maps KML Document.
now i wanna parse its string to Double
this is my code :

```
public Double getLatitude(){
    for(int posisi = GPS_NAME.indexOf(","); posisi > GPS_NAME.length(); posisi++){
        TEMP_LAT = "" + GPS_NAME.indexOf(posisi);
    }
    GPS_LATITUDE = Double.valueOf(TEMP_LAT);

    return GPS_LATITUDE;
}

public Double getLongitude(){
    int posisiakhir = GPS_NAME.indexOf(",");
    for(int i = 0; i < posisiakhir; i++){
        TEMP_LON = "" + GPS_NAME.indexOf(i);
    }
    GPS_LONGITUDE = Double.valueOf(TEMP_LON);

    return GPS_LONGITUDE;
}
```

but when i try to run it i got error like this
[image]

could somebody help me solving my problems >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and also confirm `GPS_LATITUDE = Double.valueOf(TEMP_LAT);` `TEMP_LAT` is not null there - as exception is NullPointerException not NumberFormatException.

Comment: sorry Dheeresh, i cannot understand what u mean here. can u describe it for me? >_<

Comment: i want to say that please put the check there for null before using Double.parseDouble as in the log cat provided by you the exception is null pointer so looks TEMP_LAT may be null there ....

Answer (score 2):

You have null pointer exception so you should to it like this:

```
public Double getLatitude(){
    for(int posisi = GPS_NAME.indexOf(","); posisi > GPS_NAME.length(); posisi++){
        TEMP_LAT = "" + GPS_NAME.indexOf(posisi);
    }
    if (TEMP_LAT != null) {
       GPS_LATITUDE = Double.parseDouble(TEMP_LAT);
    }

    return GPS_LATITUDE;
}
```

And for converting to double rather you should use `Double.parseDouble()` or also you can use `new Double(TEMP_LAT).doubleValue()` but first approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the probable causes for the NPE, I don't really get your logic; it looks completely dodgy to me.

Just some examples:

`GPS_NAME.indexOf(",")` will either return `-1` or an index that is smaller than the length of the string in which is being searched. Then why have a condition that checks if it is larger than the length? `posisi > GPS_NAME.length()` will never be true, hence the for loops are useless...

Then inside the loops you do `TEMP_LAT = "" + GPS_NAME.indexOf(posisi)`. From the earlier remark we know that `posisi` is either `-1` or some other number that is smaller than the length of the string. So [`GPS_NAME.indexOf(posisi)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) will try to find a character repesented by the integer `posisi` (which will be a rather small number) in the string. How does that make sense?

I'd like to advise you to rethink your logic - perhaps [`String.split(",")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%28) is a good starting point.

Comment: as long as i know, If the substring str does not occur,  -1 is returned. but substring "," is occur in my String

Comment: i read from this artikel MH
http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter10/stringBufferToken.html

about using indexof in String. its said "This results in a value of 4 in the variable x. If the string holds no such character, the method returns -1."

Comment: @DevYudh: Uhm, that's exactly my point. Since when does does `-1 > someString.length()` yield `true`? Assuming the string isn't `null` (otherwise we get another NPE) the string's length will be `>= 0`. Hence, that condition in the for loop will *always* resolve to false and immediately break, which is most likely also the cause for `TEMP_LAT` remaining `null`. The loop body never gets executed...

Comment: ooohh i got the point, thanks MH.sorry im newbie at programming

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.parseDouble(TEMP_LAT);`

Comment: Kindly see his exception - it's NullPointerException. Although using `parseDouble()` method for parsing is a good suggestion, but this isn't relevant to the question.